# Google App Engine log download takes too long

Tags: google-app-engine

I wrote an application running on Google App that generates logs at very high rate. Now I need to download and process them. It says in the Admin Console that the log is around 300MB. Ideally I would like to process only small parts of the logs. Could anybody give me some pointers on how to:

1. Download only log entries in a specific time range (i.e. the timestamp of the log records fall into this range).

OR

1. If I have about 300Mb of logs, what is the quickest way to download it?. I've run the appcfg.sh command for almost an hour now and it's still running (around 250000 log records now). Is there a way to break the log down to small chunks and download them in parallel?

Many thanks,
Anh.

Comment: This morning I saw Mache: http://blog.streak.com/2012/07/export-your-google-app-engine-logs-to.html : a library to export your logs to bigquery from streak.

Comment: hi, thanks. I actually saw it before also. It looks like Streak is scheduling a background task on my app which reads and sends the data elsewhere. But I'm not sure how fast it is, and what sort of query I can do with BigQuery

Comment: Why do you want to download your log?

Comment: right, good question. Maybe BigQuery can be the tool i need. But do you know how long it takes to migrate the logs over?

Comment: Why does it matter? By the way : Exceptions can also be send by email: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/python/recording_exceptions_with_ereporter

Comment: mache is very quick and can be configured to run very often (we run it every 60 seconds so that logs are pushed over as they are generated).